# Query Nested Mongo Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, find, mongodb-query

Not sure how to query for matching directory_object_ids for a mongo db object with the follow structure.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5702e52e51c2e40f55b3fd43"),
"_revision" : 4,
"enabled" : true,
"selector" : {
    "directory_object_ids" : [
        ObjectId("56c4bfb793e0be0eb6297369"),
        ObjectId("56c4bfc293e0be0eb6297391"),
        ObjectId("56cdfc65f2325d0e6346b7fe")
    ]
}
```

I've tried

```
db.policies.find({"selector":{"directory_object_ids":{$elemMatch: {$eq:ObjectId("56cdfc65f2325d0e6346b7fe")}}}}).pretty()
```

and

```
db.policies.find({"selector":{"directory_object_ids": {$eq:ObjectId("56cdfc65f2325d0e6346b7fe")}}}).pretty()
```

with no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call directly the nested object in your `find` query :

```
db.policies.find({"selector.directory_object_ids": ObjectId("56cdfc65f2325d0e6346b7fe")}).pretty()
```

If you want to request records matching at least one among all specified item, use `$in` :

```
db.policies.find({
    "selector.directory_object_ids": {
        $in: [ObjectId("56c4bfc293e0be0eb6297391"), ObjectId("56cdfc65f2325d0e6346b7fe")]
    }
}).pretty()
```

And if you want to request records matching all specified items, use `$all` :

```
db.policies.find({
    "selector.directory_object_ids": {
        $all: [ObjectId("56c4bfc293e0be0eb6297391"), ObjectId("56cdfc65f2325d0e6346b7fe")]
    }
}).pretty()
```